# nginx rewrite utf-8 endcoded url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am using Nginx, and I want to rewrite all url with the following two params:

```
title=%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A
```

and

```
from=(any datatime)
```

to home page.

I don't know how to write the rule, would any one help me?

Edit:

I want to rewrite urls like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?days=30&from=20120122083408&limit=250&title=%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A
```

or

```
http://example.com/index.php?from=20120622063000&limit=20&title=%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A
```

or

```
http://example.com/index.php?from=20030422063000&title=%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A
```

to

```
http://example.com
```

Comment: Please give an example, how should the url look before & after rewriting?

Comment: OK. I just added some examples. See above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't support logical AND operation, but we could use "little hack":
This should help you:

```
location = /index.php {
    set $redirect "";

    # if we have get parameter "title":
    if ( $arg_title ) {
        set $redirect "Y";
    }

    # if we have get paramter "from":
    if ( $arg_from ) {
        set $redirect "${redirect}ES";
    }

    # Now in the variable $redirect should be a word "YES":
    if ( $redirect = YES ) {
        rewrite ^ / last;
    }

    ....
}
```

P.S. You also could use 302 redirect, to directly move user to **/** .

Comment: Great idea. Thanks, Sergei. The only problem now is that I want to rewrite the url only when $arg_title equals to '%E7%89%B9%E6%AE%8A' ( the string decoded to Chinese word '特殊'). How can I do that? I have tried `if ( $arg_title ~ "(*UTF8)^\x{7279}\x{6b8a}$" )`， but it didn't work.